# I have problem in connecting with an open and hidden wifi to pi using GUI and command line

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I ensured that the USB dongle is detected by pi using lsusb.On the Current Status tab of wpa_gui. Then Scan and waited for the results . I selected my wireless network and then clicked Connect. The wpa_gui just sits there with
Status: Scanning.

I have a **hidden** and **open wifi** and hence no SSID is displayed. I choose the BSSID from the list which i already know from netsh in command prompt in my windows pc. 
Network type:Infrastructure
Authentication:Open
Encryption:None

My lsmod lists 8192cu.ko module
What can be wrong?

Using the command line

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan essid "MYSSID"
  wlan0     Scan completed :
         Cell 01 - Address: //redacted//
            ESSID:"Not my wifi"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
            Encryption key:on
            Bit Rates:65 Mb/s
            Extra:wpa_ie=//redacted//
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Quality=58/100  Signal level=100/100
  Cell 02 - Address: //redacted//
            ESSID:"Some other wifi"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
            Encryption key:on
            Bit Rates:65 Mb/s
            Extra:wpa_ie=//redacted//
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Quality=54/100  Signal level=23/100
  Cell 14 - Address: //redacted//
            ESSID:"MYSSID"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
            Encryption key:off
            Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
```

my /etc/network/interfaces

```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  allow-hotplug wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
  iface default inet dhcp
```

In etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
   ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1


    network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    auth_alg=OPEN
     }
```

Comment: Try adding `scan_ssid=1` to your wpa_supplicant.conf. ie, `network=` part should look like this. `network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    auth_alg=OPEN      scan_ssid=1
     }`

Comment: Also add `ap_scan=2` after `update_config=1` line.

Comment: @dastaan.. the problem was due to the limited capacity of the wifi network of my company. The IT service said I should try connecting to the open wifi when there is less traffic. I got wifi in my pi using a hotspot in my pc..Thank you-

Comment: Glad to know that it's been solved. :) Cheers.